# use grep -A and -v switches together

Tags: parsing, grep

The `grep -v` invert the matching so I can *exclude* lines from input/files.

Is it possible to exclude two lines if a pattern matches?

`printf "foo\nbar\nbaz\n" | grep -A1 -v foo`

does not work. I expect that this code outputs only `baz`, but it outputs

```
bar
baz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-A`, `-B` and `-C` flags cause the specified number of context lines to be printed for each line which meet the search condition. When you use `-v`, the search condition is inverted, so the selected lines are those which don't match the pattern. Consequently, `grep -A1 -v foo` prints all lines which don't contain `foo`, as well as the lines following the lines which don't contain `foo`.

I understand that that is not what you are looking for, but it is the way `grep` is specified to work. As far as I know, there is no option which *suppresses* the printing of lines after a pattern matches.

However, it is easy enough to accomplish this feat using `awk`:

```
awk '/foo/{c=2} c{c--;next;} 1'
```

Note that `awk` uses Posix Extended Regular Expressions, like `grep -E`. The regex must be surrounded with slashes, and that means you need to backslash-escape any slash which needs to be matched. Other than that, it will be pretty similar to `grep`.